# Use Excel file on my website server as an inventory file?

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I hope this question makes enough sense.

I have an Excel sheet with about 150 stock items. These stock items have columns such as "Batch Number - Expiry Date - Quantity"; as an example.

I'm using Joomla for our small company website. Is there ANY way I can implement this Excel file and create a point-of-sale system? As in, use this Excel sheet as a live stock which can display in the site? There must be some scripts or something to that effect.

I can use Excel online and sharepoint, but that only shows the stock, you can't place orders and such. Is there any other good inventory management software?

Thanks

Comment: The real question is why do you want to do that? Why not set up a database and do it for real? I can understand that you want to keep it simple but in reality I think you are actually making it harder. Also, I don't know how phpexcel (or similar) works if two users access at the same time. I know if two users read a text file at the same time php thinks the file is missing and creates a new file, and overwriting the existing one. That can be problematic even if it's only 150 SKU.

Comment: Ah I see. Luckily we only have 4 users who will use that specific page. Joomla does have phpmyadmin, which has mysql. I'll have to create a new table with all the information and import it into phpmyadmin via a CSV file.Thanks for the reply and information :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should parse that excel file and insert it to joomla database, then you can manage that stock data online, and data will be updated in real time for

Comment: Do you have any tips on the parsing for Excel to joomla? Otherwise, I would just research it on google. However, any tips and tricks are appreciated. Thanks for the reply. Joomla does use phpmyadmin as a database, which does have SQL.

Comment: i think you should have some custom work, you can use this library to read excel into php https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Answer (score 2):

It seems you should consider *what you are really asking* as this looks a lot like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

You are asking how to interact with an Excel spreadsheet from PHP to treat that spreadsheet as a database. Is there a reason why you wouldn't use an actual database?

Unless there is a particular reason why a SQL database (or NoSQL) doesn't suit your needs it would serve you to read more about how to use them with PHP before trying to repurpose a round peg (Excel spreadsheet) to fit into a square hole (Database)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an exceptional PHP library that allows to manipulate Microsoft Excel files - [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel). You could generate spreadsheets on the fly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will have a look into it!

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, there are probably better solutions using a database but a recently released new free extension [NoK List](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/news-display/tables-a-lists/nok-list) allows you to administer records in a CSV file from the front-end and back-end of a Joomla website.

You might find additional similar extensions at: https://extensions.joomla.org/category/news-display/tables-a-lists

Comment: Thanks a lot Neil! I will definitely have a look at it. Yes it is quite difficult to find the right solution. I mean, we have an ERP system, Dynamics AX, and I'd like to integrate the web services with the stock we have in Dynamics.. However, let's just say the higher-ups have been busy with implementing this system a long time now. So we started using a daily updated Excel file just temporarily.